# Micronaut - How to inject Hibernate validator

Tags: kotlin, bean-validation, micronaut

I am using the Hibernate validation mechanism in my Micronaut project as the documentation suggests.

Unfortunately, I need to react to validation errors manually and handle the errors with specific exceptions. Thus, I can not use the recommended way of validating method arguments

```
fun doStuff(@Valid argument: MyArgument): ... {...}
```

I want to inject the Validator to my class, call it and process the results myself. In Spring this was easily doable. Micronaut unfortunately tells me it does not know how to provide a validator:

```
Message: No bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] exists
```

My class looks like this

```
import javax.validation.Validator

@Controller
class MyController(val validator: Validator) {...}
```

Am I missing something? I read somewhere that there should be a default validation bean factory available as I am using Micronaut v1.1.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a `javax.validation.ValidatorFactory` that will delegate to whatever implementation you have on the classpath.

Starting in 1.2.0 (not released yet), you will be able to inject a `io.micronaut.validation.validator.Validator` that is Micronaut's implementation of validation that doesn't use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

One can provide the validator by adding a Factory that provides the Validation bean like this:

```
@Factory
class ValidatorFactory {
    @Singleton
    fun validator(): Validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().validator
}
```

This adds the necessary Validator bean to the application context and makes it available.